# Can I use XSLT to make separate output files(like xhtml) from a single XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I'm new to XML with experience with css. I have a single XML file that I am trying to style for the web. The file can be kind of complex so I would like to display it in separate pages so users can navigate between parts of the XML file. For example, there is encoded descriptive information that I'd like to be on a separate page that can link to the parts of the XML file that they pertain to.

It seems like the ideal way to do this would be to use Xquery within xhtml, but browsers don't support it and I need to do it client-side. I've also looked into XQIB but I couldn't get the query to grab information from a separate XML file.

Can I use XSLT within different xhtml files to pull information out of my XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to run XSLT *in the browser* rather than on the server, for some reason.

Yes you can, at least with an ajax call. Each XHTML web page can fetch the XML document, and also an XSLT stylesheet, via ajax. The page can call the stylesheet with parameters specific to that page.

However it may be slow for the user, waiting for the XML and XSLT to load, and then waiting for the transformation. Especially since you will likely be loading the whole XML file for each page even though you will only be using a fraction of it for that page.